# OrangePI 0 did not load Armbian inside the microSD card after I tried to plug the card in windows system

Tags: linux, armbian

I obtained a device using OrangePI 0 with a microSD card containing the OS and necessary application for the system from my company. It uses Raspbian/Armbian as the OS. My problem is, the device no longer boots into the OS as it should after I tried to plug the memory card into a Windows system. I'm not so sure what caused the problem, but it only occurs after the event. Before that, I tried to boot the device and it was successful. The light on the ethernet port was blinking and it manage to obtain an IP address to use. I can confirm that was the last successful boot for the system based on the boot log. It stops at that date. So what I need to know are:

1. Can the bootloader on the Linux system be damaged by plugging into a windows system?
2. How can I rectify this issue and make the board boots the OS. What logs should I take a look.

Please ask if you need to see any logs of config files.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: 1. It shouldn't unless you told Windows to format it and/or it was corrupted when removing it.

Comment: I believe so too. By corrupted you mean the memory card cannot be accessed at all?